# Executable Not Found: XXXXX.app is not a valid path to an executable file

Tags: ios, xcode12.5

XXXXXX.app is not a valid path to an executable file. Please rebuild the project to ensure that all required executables are created. Check your project settings to ensure that a valid executable will be built.

Project is running proper in Real device but while running in simulator showing above error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYN0t.png)